# How do I make a Packer-based image become a Chef node once running in production?

Tags: chef-infra, digital-ocean, packer

I have a DigitalOcean Image snapshot being created with [Packer](http://packer.io) and provisioned with Chef Solo.  After I create a new Droplet based on this image, I'd like it to be a unique Chef node for my Chef server.

What's the best way to do this?  How should I tell that Droplet to become a Chef node?

Thanks,
Erik

Comment: You need to provision it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bootstrap the droplet with `knife bootstrap`: http://docs.opscode.com/knife_bootstrap.html

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.  I didn't know if it would have interfered with Chef Solo but it's fine.